# Why is the final layer Dense layer when you construct a network for classification?

Tags: deep-learning

I'm beginner of learning Deep learning.
Dense layers are fully connected and cause the overfitting but why do you use Dense layer for only the final layer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fully connected layers don't cause overfitting by themselves. They are used as final layers in some models because they can directly perform classification.

They also allow the model to be split between layers that do feature extraction (convolutional layers) and layers that do classification on those features (the fully connected ones).

Also note that the use of FC layers is decreasing as one can also use global average pooling followed by a softwax, which allows a fully convolutional network to perform classification without using FC layers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!! So helpful to build the network! I wanted to try to use Global Average Pooling but I had no idea about how to use that.

Comment: @Matis Valdenegro, I read your explanation again now then another question came up so if you show me the explanation or some links to help , I will be pleasured. Why doesn't  GlobalAveragePooling followed by a softmax need FC layers? Does a softmax cause ?

Comment: @Yuki.U GAP + softmax will already output a probability distribution, which is what you want for multi-class classification. In this case the feature maps themselves will learn a mapping from image to object classes.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I see!! Thank you so much! How GAP + softmax works is interesting!